# DateTime Conversion error when executing SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I'm getting an issue when executing a reader to retrieve some DateTimes from a table.

First, I have one page transferring over some variables to another page:

```
//calStart.SelectedDate is a DateTime value
Response.Redirect("SpecialReports_Results.aspx?userListValues=" + userListValues + "&groupListValues=" + groupListValues + "&calSelected=" + calStart.SelectedDate);
```

Then, on the new page:

```
    //To retrieve the values that were sent over
    string userListValues = Request.QueryString["userListValues"];
    string groupListValues = Request.QueryString["groupListValues"];
    string dateSelected = Request.QueryString["calSelected"];

    // SQL Server connection stuff + string argument
    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand();
    command2.Connection = gconn;

    String sql2 = "SELECT MAX([Day]) as TheDay FROM Days WHERE User_ID = @User_ID AND [Day] < '@dateSelected' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Days WHERE User_ID = @User_ID AND [DAY] >= '@dateSelected')";
    command2.CommandText = sql2;

    command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@User_ID", ""));
    command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateSelected", dateSelected));

    List<string> dates = new List<string>();

    //userID is a List<string>
    foreach (string str in userID)
    {
        command2.Parameters["@User_ID"].Value = str;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read()) //Getting error here: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    dates.Add(reader["Day"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The table `Days` is set up like so:

```
User_ID | Day
----------------------------------
10      | 2010-11-09 00:00:00.000
20      | 2015-12-06 00:00:00.000
30      | 2012-01-12 00:00:00.000
40      | 2013-07-23 00:00:00.000
```

The `Day` column is of type `DateTime`.

I have tried converting the string `dateSelected` and the `List<string>` dates to `DateTime` by doing:

```
DateTime confirmedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateSelected);
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>()
```

But I get the same error.

Note: The SQL statement does work when executed in Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Did you check the value of the `dateSelected` before `DateTime.Parse`? what is that? and what is the data type? string?

Comment: Yes, it is the same value but just as a string. Example:
`"12/1/2015 12:00:00 AM"` is a string and after the parse it becomes
`{12/1/2015 12:00:00 AM}` that is System.DateTime

Comment: What is the error exactly? On which line?

Comment: In the foreach loop, I put a comment next to the `while(reader.Read())` line which is where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to delete single quotes on your `'@dateSelected'`.

With that, your code see it as a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), not a parameter.

```
String sql2 = "SELECT MAX([Day]) as TheDay FROM Days WHERE User_ID = @User_ID AND [Day] < @dateSelected AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Days WHERE User_ID = @User_ID AND [DAY] >= @dateSelected)";
```

Since there is no implicit conversation from string to datetime, your reader try to convert this `@dateSelected` string literal to datetime and it fails.

Comment: This is correct. Additionally, it's good practice to also parse the `Request.QueryString["calSelected"]` value to a C# DateTime object before assigning it to the parameter. Otherwise, the SqlParameter constructor will create an `nvarchar` parameter, which can have painful consequences when it comes time to match the value with an index.

Comment: I removed the single quotes as you said. It gets past the first error, but now I get a `IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code` error on `dates.Add(reader["Day"].ToString());`. Some of the results should be Null which should not get added to the list. That's why I added `reader.HasRows` but maybe that isn't correct?

Comment: @pfinferno [What is an “index out of range” exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20940979/447156)

Comment: @pfinferno No, the `HasRows` check is not what you want. A NULL value still produces a row. You can check for `DBNull.Value` instead, or (even better) you can add a condition to your sql `WHERE` clause so that those records are filtered out by the database before coming back to C#.

Comment: @pfinferno your column name in Select statement is `TheDay `

Comment: Yup that was it. Thank you. Also, going to make changes as @JoelCoehoorn said to filter out the null values beforehand.